# How to make manual colorscale in plotly in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, colors, plotly, r-plotly

I am making 3D surface plot with `plotly` in `R` as below;

```
#create dataframe
df <-data.frame(x = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)), # create random data
                  y = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
                  z = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)))

#prepare surface and plot
s = interp(x = df$x, y = df$y, z = df$z,duplicate = "mean") # prepare for plot_ly plot
p <- plot_ly(x = s$x, y = s$y, z = s$z,colorscale = 'RdYlBu')%>% # plot_ly
    add_surface()
```

, which results in below figure;

[image]

Here, I would like to set "color transition from blue to red" at z = 2.5.

Is there any way to do it in plotly?

Although I am using `colorscale = 'RdYlBu'` right now, it dues not have to use it. In any way, ideal color pattern is placing "color transition" between blue and red at z = 2.5, as it is manually possible in `ggolot2` as below;

```
gg <-ggplot(df, aes(x=x, y=y, color=z)) + 
   geom_point() + 
   scale_color_gradient2(midpoint=2.5, low="blue", mid="white",high="red", space ="Lab")
```

, which results in below figure;

[image]

Do you suggest any solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(plotly)
library(akima)

df <-data.frame(x = c(rnorm(300, 3, 2.5), rnorm(150, 7, 2)), # create random data
                y = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)),
                z = c(rnorm(300, 6, 2.5), rnorm(150, 2, 2)))

s <- interp(x = df$x, y = df$y, z = df$z, duplicate = "mean") 

t <- (2.5 - min(df$z)) / (max(df$z) - min(df$z))

plot_ly(x = s$x, y = s$y, z = s$z) %>% 
  add_surface(colorscale = list(list(0,"blue"), list(t,"white"), list(1,"red")))
```